# Laravel Server Error while running php artisan serve

Tags: laravel-9

Can anyone help me how to prevent this.[Screenshot of problem here](https://ibb.co/YN26Cch)

While my system is running on php artisan serve, some clients who access the system triggers that problem and it halt the server from running. ty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it's in the image i had attached